# Dojo context menu - set menu item status dynamically

Tags: menu, dojo

I am trying to implement a context menu on a dijit tree, and the context menu should display different contents and enable/disable the menu items based on which tree node I right-clicked on. Basically what I need is a pre-processing function that gets called before the context menu is displayed where I can run some logic to determine which menu items to show/hide, enable/disable, etc. I feel like this is a very basic functionality for context menus but wasn't able to find the solution, so I'm asking people for help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Tree.html#context-menu) for version 1.7 shows how to disable menu items (last js command in snippet)

Answer (score 0):

Dijit Tree has no built-in support for context menus, but you can use the Menu widget in conjunction with the Tree. The Menu widget is used for context menus, with right-click which can really suite your use-case.

Documentation and examples here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Tree.html#context-menu
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html